# My unity Script only edits the text of two objects but not the other two

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

So I have this script where it would grab a random question and it would also randomize the answers for the question my problem is that the script only fills the first two answers but not the other two I don't know what is the problem im so confused because the code for the answers are all the same

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class QuestionData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Quistions questions;
    public Awnser answers;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _questionText;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI Awn1Text;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI Awn2Text;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI Awn3Text;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI Awn4Text;
    private int Aw1;
    private int Aw2;
    private int Aw3;
    private int Aw4;

    void Start()
    {
        AskQuestion();
    }

    public void AskQuestion()
    {
        if (CountValidQuestions() == 0)
        {
            _questionText.text = string.Empty;
            ClearQuestions();
            SceneManager.LoadScene("EndScreen");
            return;
        }

        int randomIndex;
        int QNum;
        int Aw1 = -1;
        int Aw2 = -1; // Initialize Aw2
        int Aw3 = -1; // Initialize Aw3
        int Aw4;

        do
        {
            randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, questions.questionList.Count);
            QNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 4);
        } while (questions.questionList[randomIndex].questioned);

        questions.questionList[randomIndex].questioned = true;
        _questionText.text = questions.questionList[randomIndex].question;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            int randomAnswerIndex;

            do
            {
                randomAnswerIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 4);
            } while (randomAnswerIndex == Aw1 || randomAnswerIndex == Aw2 || randomAnswerIndex == Aw3);

            int currentAnswerIndex = (randomIndex * 4) + randomAnswerIndex;

            foreach (var answerData in answers.awnserList)
            {
                Debug.Log("Answer: " + answerData.awnser + ", IsAwn: " + answerData.IsAwn);
            }

            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    Awn1Text.text = answers.awnserList[currentAnswerIndex].awnser;
                    Aw1 = randomAnswerIndex;
                    Debug.Log("Aw1: " + Aw1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Awn2Text.text = answers.awnserList[currentAnswerIndex].awnser;
                    Aw2 = randomAnswerIndex;
                    Debug.Log("Aw2: " + Aw2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Awn3Text.text = answers.awnserList[currentAnswerIndex].awnser;
                    Aw3 = randomAnswerIndex;
                    Debug.Log("Aw3: " + Aw3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Awn4Text.text = answers.awnserList[currentAnswerIndex].awnser;
                    Aw4 = randomAnswerIndex;
                    Debug.Log("Aw4: " + Aw4);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void ClearQuestions()
    {
        foreach (var question in questions.questionList)
        {
            question.questioned = false;
        }
    }

    private int CountValidQuestions()
    {
        int ValidQuestions = 0;
        foreach (var question in questions.questionList)
        {
            if (!question.questioned)
            {
                ValidQuestions++;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Questions Left: " + ValidQuestions);
        return ValidQuestions;
    }
}
```

If anyone knows the issue please help me (I know i mispealt "Question" and "answer" im just too lazy to change that)

I asked chat gpt for a solution  but it was to no avail im literally so confused because the lines for filling the answer with text  are the same and idk what I should do

Comment: You need to debug your code. Set a breakpoint at the top and then step through the code line by line and examine the state at each step. Compare the actual state to your expected state and see what is different and where. You may be able to work out the problem for yourself after that but, if you can't, you need to report your findings to us. You always need to debug your code before posting a question so, if you don't know how, stop what you're doing and learn that first.

Comment: Being lazy is very bad on this platform, people are helping you out show that you deserve. Can you at least explain what you intend with the code as a step by step guide? And show a screen shot of the inspector where you assign the text. Also show us the logs you get when you run please.

Answer (score 0):

Your script logic seems ok, at least to my naked eye (although it could be way more optimised). Check your scene references for all your TextMeshProUGUI fields. You may have double-assigned the third and fourth references.

If your scene references are correct, then as the previous answers suggested, you should debug your code and check the lines in your for loop.